# Writing a method to see if String x contains letter "G"

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I'm working on an assignment that has us fill in 8 different methods. For the particular method I'm working on, I have to see if the string contains the letter 'G' and return. I came up with something I thought would work but it isn't. Also this is a basic Java class and I'm pretty new so please explain what you did.

```
/**
 * Where is the location of the letter G (upper or lower case) in
 * the given string?
 * @param x String to check
 * @return 0 based location of first occurrence of G in x,
 *         -1 if G is not present.
 */
public static int indexOfG( String x ) {
    char[] array = x.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == 'G'){
            return i ;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.  "It doesn't work" is not sufficient.

Comment: For one thing, you're missing a `return -1;` at the end (after the `for` loop), in case you didn't find the letter in the string. Also, should the method be case-insensitive? If so, change your `if` to: `if(array[i] == 'G' || array[i] == 'g')`.

Comment: Why create a character array? As others said, you can use x,indexOf(). If you are not allowed to do that (i.e., if you are required to write it yourself), why not test on x.charAt(i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

There is already an indexOf for Strings.

From Java documentation of Oracle:

> indexOf(String str)
>   Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.

**EDIT**

Since using String methods may not be allowed, i can give you some hints about implementing your own indexOf.

```
// This is a more concise and easier to read version 
public static int indexOfG(String str){

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i){
        if(str.charAt(i) == 'G' || str.charAt(i) == 'g') return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You should try to set this method as a generic one, that accepts a second parameter as the char you want to find.

Comment: `indexOf(int ch)` would probably be better.

Comment: @AntonH in the documentation he can find other overloads so no big deal

Comment: A lot of times in beginning java classes the use of certain standard java library methods are disallowed.  I'm guessing this is the case with this class.  He won't be able to use indexOf

Comment: i have added a simple implementation with a for loop since factory methods may not bet allowed.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help! And my apologies if I have broken posting guidelines; I'm new here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static int indexOfG( String x ) {
    char[] array = x.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if((array[i] == 'G') || (array[i] == 'g')){
            return i ;
        }   
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Above code is giving the correct position of zero-based first position of 'g'.

Alternativly you can also use below method of java string

public int indexOf(int ch)